# Mum ale recipes/references/sources?

Tags: recipe, beer-styles

As some of you may be aware I have a strange obsession with old beers styles and trying to recreate historical styles.

My next idea is to try and create the style Mum. "This is a style originally from Germany but popular in Britain from 1660 to early 19th Century.".[1]

Does anyone know of any sources for this, any contemporary accounts or even some old recipes for this beer style. So, far I have a one line metion on wikipedia and a link from there shared here.

[ 1. http://zythophile.co.uk/2012/05/22/endangered-beers/ ]

==== EDIT ====

Found a couple of other interesting links I need to properly investigate:

This one has a good historical look at the style:
https://witteklavervier.nl/en/history/mum

This contains some guide to a recipe, I think given the bad translation and my terrible schoolboy German:
http://www.kruenitz1.uni-trier.de/cgi-bin/getKRArticles.tcl?tid=005_15+opt=1-0

NB. I do not mind if the sources are in English, German or Dutch.

Comment: http://sixpoint.com/blog/mad-scientists-series-18-brunswick-mumme/

Comment: Seems like there was a lot of fake recipes running around way back in history. I can't quite figure out if there really were about 50 different ingredients or it was just a heavy brown ale made for export. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "Brew Files" Podcast there were two episodes with an author who wrote a book on historic german beer styles. Maybe he can help you?!

https://www.experimentalbrew.com/podcast/brew-files-episode-32-german-beer-history-andreas

He also has a blog where he references the "Brunswik Mumm" http://dafteejit.com/2016/01/historic-german-beers-that-did-not-conform-to-the-reinheitsgebot/

Edit: In the comments of this blog post they are talking about the recipe of the Mumm: http://dafteejit.com/2018/02/my-new-book/

Comment: finally bought that book on historical german beer styles, loking forward to having a proper read over the weekend

Comment: Nice, have fun brewing it!